# vary slow frame rate when calling HoughCircles() method from onCameraFrame, OpenCV, Android/Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

extremely slow frame rates when using the openCV Java method in android for detecting circular shaped objects in images

```
 Imgproc.HoughCircles(mGray, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50);
```

when i remove this method it runs fast, but after adding this method inside of this callback

```
  public Mat onCameraFrame(final CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
```

the frame rate slows to 1 to 2 frames per second,  I don't understand why it gets so slow, i tried putting this method in a separate thread and it would not help, the only thing that worked is to use a counter and and an if statement to run the method every 10 frames.

in the OpenCV examples there is a sample project called face detection and it has both a native C++ and Java camera versions and they both are vary fast, how is it possible that when I use similar code I get this slow constipated action from OpenCV?

is there something i am doing wrong here?  In the face detection project from openCV examples they take every frame and they don't launch a separate thread.  how do I fix this problem and make my code run fast like the sample projects in OpenCV?

in a different project I am also having the same problem of slow frame rate, in this practice project where I am not using openCV, it is just the android Camera class only,  in that I am taking the image from the onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) method and doing some light processing like converting the YUV format from the byte array into a bitmap and putting that into another view on the same screen as the camera view, and the result is vary slow frame rate.

EDIT: In some additional experimentation I added the Imgproc.HoughCircles() method to the OpenCV face Detection sample project. putting this method inside the onCameraFrame method of the java detector.

the result is the same as in my project, it became vary slow. so the HoughCircles method probably takes more processing power than the face detection method CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(), however that does not explain the fact I watched other circle detection projects on youTube and in their videos the frame rate is not slowed down.  that is why I think there is something wrong with what I am doing.

here is a sample of the code I am using

```
public class CircleActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

Mat                    mRgba;
Mat                    mGray;
File                   mCascadeFile;
CascadeClassifier      mJavaDetector;
CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;
LinearLayout linearLayoutOne;
ImageView imageViewOne;
int counter = 0;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i("OPENCV", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();

            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coffee);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.fd_activity_surface_view);

        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mGray = new Mat();
        mRgba = new Mat();

    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mGray.release();
        mRgba.release();

    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(final CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
                mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
                mGray = inputFrame.gray();
          if(counter == 9) {

              MatOfRect circles = new MatOfRect();

                Imgproc.HoughCircles(mGray, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50);

                // returns number of circular objects found
                Log.e("circle check", "circles.cols() " +  circles.cols());

           }

     counterAdder();

     return mRgba;

    } // end oncamera frame

   public void counterAdder() { 
        if (counter > 10) {
            counter = 0;

        }
        counter++;

    }


 }
```

Comment: have you tried reducing the resolution of the camera frames?

Comment: that is an interesting idea, i did not try that yet, was using the full frame.  i will try it,  i was able to use a timer to take only one frame per 2 seconds an evaluate that frame and then wait the 2 seconds before pulling another frame, that was by registering a null object to the listener, and then re-setting that listener again so it starts calling the onCameraFrame() call back method again.

Comment: You can probably try this mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640, 480);. you can reduce the resolution bit more to get higher fps up to 20fps

Comment: that reduction of frame size to 640, 480, works great,  the frame rate became much better and it is usable now, at that resolution I do not notice vary much reduction in the image quality. that is a good compromise between image quality and image size.

Comment: great that its working, i will post this as an answer then

Comment: that comparison to a priest is hilarious :)!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reducing resolution of camera frames might help

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640, 480);
```

Answer (score 1):

From my brief experience, the running time for HoughCircles greatly depends on the image. A textured image with a lot of potential circles takes much longer than an image with a uniform background. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I' ve faced this problem either. 
I' ve tried to decrease the camera resolution with `mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(1280, 720);`

However it is still slow. I' ve been trying to work parallel with Threads, but it is still 3.5FPS.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    //System.gc();
    carrierMat = inputFrame.gray();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new MultThread(carrierMat, this));
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return carrierMat;
}
```

My MultThread class is just like this

```
public class MultThread implements Runnable {
private Mat source;
private Context context;

public MultThread(Mat source, Context context) {
    this.source = source;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //output = General.Threshold(source);
    int x = General.MSERP(source);
    Log.i("MtMTxtDtc:Main","x: " + x);
    if (x > 10){
        ((Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(500);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform the Hough Circle transform in the background not in the main activity!

Otherwise your app response will be too slow and it may be killed by the operating system due to Application Not Responding (ANR) error.

You need to add this class to your main activity and you are good to go.

```
 private class HoughCircleTransformTask
        extends AsyncTask<Mat, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Mat mGray) {

        MatOfRect circles = new MatOfRect();

        Imgproc.HoughCircles(mGray, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50);

        // returns number of circular objects found 
        // then display it from onPostExecute()
        return circles.cols();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer circlesCols){

        // This is only logging
        // You can display it in a TextView as well in the main activity
        Log.e("circle check", "circles.cols() " +  circles.cols());

    }
}
```

And just call it from onCameraFrame with one line of code only

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(final CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        if(counter == 9) {
            // call AsyncTask   
            new HoughCircleTransformTask().execute(mGray);
        }

        counterAdder();
        return mRgba;

    } // end oncamera frame
```